# Remove white space before a quote alone in a footnote

Tags: footnotes, quoting, white-space

In my document I need to put sometimes a quote alone in a footnote. The problem is in this case a white line is inserted before the quote.

How to get rid of it?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,10pt]{article}

\begin{document}

Text with a footnote which contains a quote alone\footnote{\begin{quote}This is a quotation and I don't want empty line before. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.\end{quote}}.
Text with a footnote which contains a quotation introduced by some words\footnote{Here is a quotation:\begin{quote}This is a quotation with introductory text. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.\end{quote}}.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that I have tried to use the `quoting` package with a `vskip=0pt` setting, with no effect.

Ideally, I would like to define a new environment, say `footnotequote`, which would solve this empty line problem when the quote is alone, but also keep the default display when an introductory text is given before the quote as in second example.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Like `\newevironment{fnquote}{\vspace{-\bigskipamount}\begin{quote}}{\end{quote}}`?

Comment: @jon : Thanks, this indeed solves the problem for the first footnote. However it modifies the behavior of the second one. I would prefer a more general solution (be able to use the same environment in both cases).

Comment: The footnote text starts with an invisible rule. The quote environment can't know if there is only this rule or some real text before it so it can't change its behaviour. Beside this such quotes (and other lists) in footnotes look imho bad.  It makes footnotes to important.

Comment: As far as I understand what you want, that's not possible. (Anyway, in my opinion, the unintroduced quotation is, stylistically, a bad idea.)

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will take this into account. I'll consider simply use font shape, rather than indent, to distinguish quotation from normal text.